# allocatable function parameters and automatic vectorization

Tags: fortran, vectorization, gfortran

Can sb. explain the difference between passing `pointer` and `allocatable` subroutine parameters in Fortran? I do not understand why the following function does *not* vectorize in gfortran 7.2:

```
subroutine test0(fsm, im)
implicit none
real, dimension(:), pointer :: fsm
integer, intent(in) :: im
integer i

do i = 1,im
   fsm(i) = fsm(i)*2
end do
end subroutine test0
```

while it does vectorize (just like in C) if I use `allocatable` attribute for the dummy `fsm` argument. I compile using the following command line

```
gfortran -mavx -O3 -ftree-vectorize -c loops.f90 -fopt-info-vec-note
```

When using `pointer` gfortran reports a much higher vectorization cost. So is there an important difference in how the arguments are passed (e.g., indirection, pointer to pointer vs. passing by value), or is this a gfortran problem?

Comment: If you add the `contiguous` attribute to the pointer version, does it vectorize?

Comment: Stupid, thought about assumed shape instead of allocatable. I think francescalus might be right. Try also an assumed shape array `(:)` and an explicit shape array `(n)`. You might observe a similar difference.

Comment: @francescalus indeed, that does it :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compiler may be able better to optimize when an object is *contiguous*.  Vectorization here may, for example, be limited to the case where the object is known to be contiguous at compilation.

An array allocated by an `allocate` statement is always contiguous.  A dummy argument which is a pointer array need not be contiguous.  Here seems to be the difference observed.

However, an array pointer may be given the `contiguous` attribute.  Such an array is then contiguous.  A restriction on this pointer is that it may be pointer associated only with a contiguous target.

Similar experience may be had with assumed-shape arrays.  Explicit shape arrays are also contiguous.